# Avoid Method Duplication in Controllers Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, code-duplication

I have below scope method which is repeating in 5 differnt controllers, this is causing increase in my code duplication percentage, is there a way to write this code in single place and access it, without using $rootScope.

Controllers code is:

```
  $scope.keys = function (obj) {
        return CommonService.getKeyValuePair(obj);
    };
```

Comment: directive? 4 more to go

Comment: Can reduce to a single line: `$scope.keys = CommonService.getKeyValuePair;` Not much else you're going to do about that.

Comment: @Ankh that again i have to add it in remaing controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arrow function see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

$scope.keys = obj => CommonService.getKeyValuePair(obj);

This reduce your function in one instruction.